# What functions are fired in iOS between TabBarViews?

Tags: ios, view, tabs, switch-statement, tabbar

If you have a storyboard with a tab bar view controller with two tabs, what functions are triggered from one tab to the other? ViewWillAppear is not triggered between tab presses is there another function called to trigger things like data reloads, etc?

Comment: see UITabBarControllerDelegate and its shouldSelectViewController and didSelectViewController methods

Comment: This function does not get called on clicking from one tab to the next.

Comment: Yes it does, as long as you've set an object as the delegate on your tab bar controller.

Answer (score 0):

A method from `UITabBarControllerDelegate` is called, the method is `tabBarController(_:didSelect:)`. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621173-tabbarcontroller).

Comment: This function does not get called on clicking from one tab to the next.

Comment: @Jeeves Yes, it is, the documentation says so. But it is called on the UITabBarController, not on the "tabs", i.e. the children UIViewControllers.